# Prettier adds space before and after angle brackets of tags in JSX in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am trying to prettify a jsx file after save but [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) is adding space between `<>`. for example the `<p>` changes to `< p >` and this is raising issue on `jsx`

```
const elem = <h1> Hello React </h1>;
    console.log(elem);
```

to

```
const elem = < h1 > Hello React < /h1>;
console.log(elem);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you by any chance have [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) installed as well? There is an issue documenting a known conflict with that extension.

To solve this, add the following to your workspace configuration:

```
"beautify.ignore": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx"
]
```